# How create new database for testing

Tags: database

```
/**
 * Get template folder
 */ 
public List<SelectOption> getFolderList() {

    // Initialize a selectoption list
    List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();

    // Get template folder
    List<Folder> folderTemplate = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Folder WHERE Type = 'Email'];

    if(folderTemplate.size() > 0) {
        for (Folder folder : folderTemplate){
            options.add(new SelectOption(folder.Id,folder.Name));
        }

        // Get email template default
        if(!onChangeEventFlag) {
            // Get currentFolderID
            String currentFolderID = folderTemplate[0].Id;

            // Initialize a emailTemplates
            emailTemplates = new List<SelectOption>();

            // Get email template by current folder ID
            List<EmailTemplate> templateList = [Select Id, Name, IsActive From EmailTemplate Where IsActive = true AND FolderID=:currentFolderID];

            // Add email template to list
            if(templateList.size() >  0) {
                for (EmailTemplate emailTemplate : templateList){
                    emailTemplates.add(new SelectOption(emailTemplate.Id , emailTemplate.Name));
                }
            } else {
                emailTemplates.add(new SelectOption('0', NO_EMAIL_TEMPLATE_ERROR_MESSAGE));
            }
        }
    } else {
        options.add(new SelectOption('0', NO_TEMPLATE_FOLDER_ERROR_MESSAGE));
    }

    return options;
}
```

I want to write unit test for this List.  This is my code:

```
/**
 * getFolderList test
 */
@isTest
static void GetFolderListTestCase1() {
    // Create data
    BulkEmailSenderController controller = new BulkEmailSenderController();

    Test.startTest();

    List<SelectOption> testoptions = controller.getFolderList();

    Test.stopTest();

    System.assertEquals(2,testoptions.size());
}
```

However it's getting current database. I want create a new database to check in case folderTemplate no record. How do you it? Please help. Thanks all

Answer (score 1):

Tests do not see most pre-exisiting data that is in an org with the exception of a few types - see [Isolation of Test Data from Organization Data in Unit Tests](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_testing_data_access.htm). This allows tests to setup their own data and assert without creating a new database. While `Folder` isn't included in that documentation, it is one of the types that is **not** isolated.

For these (rare) cases typically you have to change your non-test code to make it testable. For example in this case you might add this variable to the class:

```
@TestVisible private static final String FOLDER_TYPE = 'Email';
```

and modify the query to use it:

```
List<Folder> folderTemplate = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Folder WHERE Type = :FOLDER_TYPE];
```

and then in the test case where you want to have no records set a type that does not exist:

```
YourClassName.FOLDER_TYPE = 'NonExistantType';
```

Using [@TestVisible](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_annotation_testvisible.htm) helps make it clear that the variable is only used in tests rather than the normal logic.